# Find $\lim_{x \to +\infty}(x^{{1}/{x}}-1)^{{1}/{\ln x}}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}&=\exp \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left( x^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{\ln x}\\
&=\exp \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left(e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}-1\right)}{\ln x}\\
&=\exp \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left({\frac{\ln x}{x}}\right)}{\ln x}\\
&=\exp \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\ln x-\ln x}{\ln x}\\
&=\exp \lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(\frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x}-1\right)\\
&=\exp(-1)\\
&=\frac{1}{e},
\end{align*}
where, namely, the process from the 2nd line to the 3rd line, we used theses facts that
\begin{align*}
e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}-1&=\frac{\ln x}{x}+\frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^3+\cdots\\
&=\frac{\ln x}{x}\left[1+\frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{\ln x}{x}+\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac{\ln x}{x}\left[1+O\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\right],
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln \left(e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}-1\right)}{\ln x}&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}+\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left[1+O\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\right]}{\ln x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}+\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}+\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left[\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\frac{\ln x}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right]\\
&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)}{\ln x}.
\end{align*}

**Please correct me if I'm wrong! Hope you see other solutions.**

Comment: Your result is right, the searched limit is equal $$\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How about the process?

Comment: I used a similiar way.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is the desired limit then $$\log L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log(x^{1/x}-1)}{\log x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(x(x^{1/x}-1)) -\log x } {\log x} $$ Now $$x(x^{1/x}-1)=\log x\cdot \frac{\exp((\log x) /x) - 1}{(\log x) /x} =f(x) \log x $$ where $f(x) \to 1$. And hence $$\log(x(x^{1/x}-1))=\log f(x) +\log\log x$$ It follows that $$\log L=-1+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log f(x)} {\log x} +\frac{\log\log x} {\log x} =-1$$ and hence $L=1/e$.